# Accessing SMS from USB modem to be uploaded for Android app

Tags: java, php, android, c, sms

I'm developing an Android app that will monitor the height of the flood. The data that will be used are from a SMS message that will be received by a USB modem. The data from the SMS will then be uploaded to a internet Server or FTP. This data will be downloaded by an Android App.
My Question is how to access this SMS from the USB modem. I'm much familiar with C, and PHP and other Web related language. Any suggestion on what language to use just to Access the SMS? thanks. :D

Comment: I would suggest to use a service such as Twilio, that is if it is useable in your world location of course, as it provides a very simple method of getting any SMS you receive to your Twilio number. http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms

Comment: It's not so much a question of language, as if the USB modem exposes SMS in a form you can work with.  As others have said, there may be better options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a that using a USB modem to receive sms is going to be your best option. Seeing that you are familiar with php and other web languages have you considered trying out the [Twilio SMS API](http://www.twilio.com/sms/api)?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. :D I've read about Twillio SMS, but I saw that the cost are High. is there any similar service that is for Free?